# Error in Excel VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy some columns of an excel sheet to another sheet.

I have written the code, which doesnt work. It gets into an infinite loop, and exits with an error. The code is:

```
Sub customCopy()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


j = 1
For i = 1 To 700
   If i Mod 5 = 2 Then
       Columns(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
   End If
   If i Mod 5 = 3 Then
       Columns(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
   End If
   If i Mod 5 = 4 Then
       Columns(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
   End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Please help..

Comment: What is there error and where does it occur? Did you try stepping through the code in single-step mode to find out why the error occurs?

Comment: Error code 1004 - "We cant paste because the Copy and the Paste area are not the same size".
i is not getting incremented, and the same row is getting copied infinite times..

Comment: This error appears once `i` equals `2`, I assume, i.e. the first time your copy code should run!?

Comment: Yes.. And the second column is pastes infinite times in sheet 2

Comment: You can't copy an entire column to anywhere besides row 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying a column into a row won't work.............**a row is too small!**